# when perfoming a multiple row updates, how do i access other form element values, apart from the checkbox?

Tags: php, mysql, html

i wrote a piece of code to do multiple row deletions based on ticked check boxes.
Now i need to mordify it to do multiple row updates. 
i have been failing to access the textbox values for each row.

here's my code, in general.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["SaveComments"])  && isset($_POST["SaveEachComment"]))
{
    while(list($key, $val) = each($_POST["SaveEachComment"]))
    {
        if($val == 'commentbox')
        {

            // do the update here. $val contains the ID
        }
    }
}
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="checkbox" <?php echo 'name="SaveEachComment['.$row["comment"].']" ';?> value="commentbox" id="commentbox" />
    <input type="text" name="rowcomment" size="55" value="<?php echo $comment;?>" />
    <input type="submit"   name="SaveComments" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your PHP code to refer to your textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added a `for` loop to print multiple form fields. Obviously your iteration would be as many as number of rows, so you can change that part of the code. But try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["SaveComments"])  && isset($_POST["SaveEachComment"]))
{
    while(list($key, $val) = each($_POST["SaveEachComment"]))
    {
        if($val == 'commentbox')
        {
                echo $_POST['rowcomment'][$key] . "<br />\n";

            // do the update here. $val contains the ID
        }
    }
}
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
<?php for ($i=0; $i<11; $i++) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" <?php echo 'name="SaveEachComment['.$i.']" ';?> value="commentbox" id="commentbox" />
    <input type="text" name="rowcomment[<? echo $i?>]" size="55" value="<?php echo $comment;?>" />
        <br />
<?php } ?>
    <input type="submit"   name="SaveComments" value="submit"  />
</form>
```